# Give a regular expression over Σ = {a,b}...?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

The question asks to give a regular expression over Σ = {a,b} in a formal representation (not java) that generates the following languages:

1. L1 = {x|x contains the substring abab}
2. L2 = {x|x has odd length}
3. L3 = {x|x does not end in ab}

I have no clue how to write a regular expression. What would the answers be and if you could explain why I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: this website will teach you and show you what you might need. https://regexone.com/

Comment: @Anand Regex != scientific regular expression

Comment: @Lucero I guess I misinterpreted, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many notations for regular expressions that differ in details. Your solutions will look something like:

1. Σ*·abab·Σ*
2. a·{aa,bb,ab,ba}* \cup b·{aa,bb,ab,ba}*
3. Σ*·{bb,a} \cup {b, \lambda}

where \cup is set union/OR and \lambda is the empty string.